# make apache mod_rewrite rols dynamic from db?

Tags: mod-rewrite, dynamic

i have mod_rewrite rols that hard coded and i want to make it dynamic 
can i fatch somehow the users names from db ? or other variables i define in the config file ?
? 
this is what i have now :

```
RewriteRule ^/user01(.*) http://$1localhost:8086/RPC2 [P]
RewriteRule ^/user02(.*) http://$1localhost:8088/RPC2 [P]
RewriteRule ^/user03(.*) http://$1localhost:8089/RPC2 [P]
RewriteRule ^/user04(.*) http://$1localhost:8090/RPC2 [P]
RewriteRule ^/user05(.*) http://$1localhost:8091/RPC2 [P]
```

as you can see each user i need to define it hard coded , can it be dynamic from db ?

Answer (score 2):

How about a [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap)?  You'd need to write it a custom lookup handler if you want the lookups to happen against an actual database, but the text file format might fit your needs.

As a side-note: by putting user-provided input in the host-part of the proxy address, you're vulnerable to [CVE-2011-3368](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2011-3368).  Make sure your Apache has been patched for that.